# How to set next js custom path when user have multitenant

Tags: reactjs, next.js, router

I want to make an application for offering multi tenant.
I don’t know the word(multi tenant) is correct.
For example, A user have one userId as (hey188)
The user can have below 3 paths that used for url as (apple, grape, hotdog.. and so on)
The user can have a lot of menu and submenu.
so we want to present this path and menu in url.
For example,

```
www.domain.com/apple/buy/buydetail
www.domain.com/grape/buy/buylist
www.domain.com/hotdog/buy/buylist
```

How to set the path apple/grape/hotdog in Next.js ?

Because apple/grape/hotdog are not page.
And apple/grape/hotdog data are called by api.
But buydetail/buylist are page.

And we should validate whether the user have correct path when user lend page.

```
www.domain.com/orange/buy/buylist
```

I can not find the way to set this path and router.

Please let me know. Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you set your router? If it's there, could you show us how you set it up?

Comment: @NickVu  This is a reference for multi-tenant!
https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-multi-tenant-application
So I write history for file structure! in medium
https://medium.com/@cocoball200/file-structure-for-multi-tenant-in-next-js-a18ba97ffcb1
I hope It is helpful!